# Unable to attach file android studio

Tags: java

When you select an audio file and then click the Send button, the Mail application opens and all entries are included except for the audio file, where a notification appears in the Mail application “Unable to attach the file.”
public class EmailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> audioPickerLauncher;
private static final int PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST = 1;
private Uri audioUri;
Button selectAudio, sendBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email);

    selectAudio = findViewById(R.id.btnChooseFile);
    selectAudio.setOnClickListener( v -> chooseAudioFile(selectAudio));

    sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnSendEmail);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> sendEmail(sendBtn));

    audioPickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                        audioUri = data.getData();
                        displayFileName(audioUri);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "تم اختيار الملف الصوتي", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}


public void chooseAudioFile(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    audioPickerLauncher.launch(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        audioUri = data.getData();
        displayFileName(audioUri);
        Toast.makeText(this, "تم اختيار الملف الصوتي", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private void displayFileName(Uri fileUri) {
    if (fileUri != null) {
        String fileName = getFileName(fileUri);
        TextView textViewFileName = findViewById(R.id.textViewFileName);

        String fileLabel = getString(R.string.file_name_label, fileName);
        textViewFileName.setText(fileLabel);
    }
}

private String getFileName(Uri fileUri) {
    String result = null;

    if (Objects.equals(fileUri.getScheme(), "content")) {
        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (displayNameIndex != -1) {
                    result = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (result == null) {
        result = fileUri.getLastPathSegment();
    }

    return result;
}

public void sendEmail(View view) {
    EditText editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextEmail.setText(getString(R.string.email));
    EditText editTextSubject = findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    EditText editTextDetails = findViewById(R.id.editTextDetails);
    EditText editTextSpeed = findViewById(R.id.editTextSpeed);
    EditText editTextRhythm = findViewById(R.id.editTextRhythm);

    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
    String details = editTextDetails.getText().toString().trim();
    String speed = editTextSpeed.getText().toString().trim();
    String rhythm = editTextRhythm.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty() || subject.isEmpty() || details.isEmpty() || audioUri == null || speed.isEmpty() || rhythm.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "يرجى ملء جميع الحقول", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Encode subject, details, speed, and rhythm before adding to the Uri
    String encodedSubject = Uri.encode(subject);
    String encodedDetails = Uri.encode(details);
    String encodedSpeed = Uri.encode(speed);
    String encodedRhythm = Uri.encode(rhythm);

    // Create mailto Uri with encoded subject, details, speed, and rhythm
    Uri mailtoUri = Uri.parse("mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + encodedSubject +
            "&body=" + encodedDetails + "%0A%0Aسرعة الملف النصي: " + encodedSpeed +
            "%0Aاسم الإيقاع: " + encodedRhythm);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mailtoUri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audioUri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // تأكيد إذن القراءة

    try {
        Log.d("EmailActivity", "Mailto URI: " + mailtoUri.toString());
        Log.d("EmailActivity", "Audio URI: " + audioUri.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "لا يوجد تطبيق بريد إلكتروني مثبت.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

I tried several solutions, as my experience was simple, but to no avail